# Shape with multiple circles

Tags: android

I want to draw a circle of color 1 inside a circle of color 2. Both of them have stroke and its inside is transparent. This should be used as a background of a button.

Something like this (but green and red are next to each other - no gap in between. Sorry, I don't have any graphical program where I could draw them so they're next to each other.)

[image]

Is there a way how to do it in XML ?

I was thinking of doing it using shape XML but layers are scaled so layers would be on top of each other so only 1 color would be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a layer list with insets in order to avoid the inner circle to lurk out from the outer circle, like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <inset android:inset="4dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <stroke
                    android:width="4dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You set the size and background of the button like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_green" />
```

It then looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FF0000"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#00FF00"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can change the `width` and `height` of the `size` element to get a different ring width.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by defining two drawable resources both circle with different stroke colors and puting them in a layer-list drawable one on top of the other, with different ofsets which give then the effect you need:

Inner circle **inner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorRed"
        android:width="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

Outer circle **outer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorGreen"
        android:width="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

Button background **background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/outer"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inner"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>
```

And this is final result

[image]